# How can I pass referrer details via an HTML element in Safari?

Tags: html, safari, referrer, referrer-policy

My site has the Referrer-Policy header configured to "no-referrer" at the server, but I'm trying to pass referrer details ad-hoc via the `referrerpolicy` HTML attribute. Chrome and Firefox seem to honor the attribute when set on an individual element, but it's ignored in Safari despite [Can I Use](https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-html_elements_a_referrerpolicy) suggesting that it should be supported.

I thought this may have been due to Apple's efforts around anti-tracking, but the behavior is the same after disabling the "Prevent cross-site tracking" feature.

Safari *does* honor referrer-policy set at the page-level via a `<meta>` tag, but I'm trying to avoid that if possible. Am I doing something wrong here or am I missing anything?

Live example: https://dvdwlsn.com/so/rp/

HTML:

```html
<a href="https://www.whatismyreferer.com/" referrerpolicy="strict-origin-when-cross-origin">RP via HTML</a>
<br>
<a href="https://www.whatismyreferer.com/">RP via Server config</a>
```